# JDK 7 Update 80 installation issue "A semi-colon found in selected path"

Tags: java, java-7

I'm trying to install JDK 7 on a Windows 7 machine and constantly getting the error "A semi-colon found in selected path" no matter what path I select for the installation.

Tried with different updates of JDK and it didn't help either.

**EDIT:** Installation log shows the following error:

Thu May 05 06:34:19 2016
:: JDK installation failed.  Return Code: 1603, ErrorCode: 0

Comment: Can you describe on which step you get this error?

Comment: This happens after selecting the installation path and clicking Next in the wizard.

Comment: What is the installation path?

Comment: I have added the installation log entry if it helps.

Comment: Installation path is C:\Java this happens regardless to path you select.

Comment: For now as a temporary solution I have extracted a zipped java home and using manually set environment variables

Comment: @Oleg Possible solution? I'm guessing you have a Russian version of Windows.  http://superuser.com/a/848361/481512

Comment: what is the java installer link that you have downloaded? By the way, please see microsoft KB article to see if that helps? https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/834484

Answer (score 4):

This error message is displayed by the Microsoft Windows Installer engine and is a general error code that indicates a problem occurred during the installation.

Read on to learn how to sidestep this speed bump.

The following is a non-exhaustive list of known causes for this error:

```
Short file name creation is disabled on the target machine.
An Install Script custom action is prototyped incorrectly.
A file is locked and cannot be overwritten.
The Microsoft Windows Installer Service is not installed correctly.
The Windows Temp folders are full.
The setup was corrupted after installation and, therefore, fails with this error during un-installation.
An older version of Install Shield Developer is being used.
A general error occurred during the installation.
Print and File sharing is not installed or enabled when installing MSDE 2000.
```

How to Avoid this Error

The following solutions have resolved this error in the majority of cases:

```
Make sure short file name creation is enabled on the target machine. You can check to ensure that the target machine does not have short file name creation disabled by navigating to the following registry entry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem

Make sure the value "NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation" is equal to 0. This indicates that short file name creation is enabled. A value of 1 indicates that this functionality is disabled. You should change the value to 0.

After modifying this value, the target machine should be rebooted before attempting to launch the setup again.
Note: If the target machine should normally have short file name creation disabled, it can be disabled after the install completes by resetting "NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation" to 1 and rebooting.
To ensure that the Windows Installer Service is properly installed and configured, it is recommended that users install the file InstmsiA.exe on Windows 95/98/Me or InstmsiW.exe on Win NT systems. These files are shipped with your InstallShield product and are located in the following location:

<Product Path>\Redist\Language Independent\i386

Empty all temporary folders. The specific temporary folders for a machine can be determined by accessing the DOS prompt and typing set. Note the values listed for TEMP and TMP, and delete all files in those locations.
Make sure no other applications, including utilities such as virus scanners, are running in the background. Close all running applications and utilities, and launch the installation again.
If this error occurs during un-installation, use the Microsoft Windows Installer CleanUp utility to uninstall the installation.

Once the installation has been successfully un-installed, you can then debug the project to determine what caused the original error.
```

Comment: I wish I had this answer 2 months back. I think it was something related to the Windows Installer service not being working correctly, however since I didn't have an answer during the time I had the issue, I had to reinstall windows to get rid of this error. However I'd love to pass on this message to my colleagues who might be facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Put your installer executable to `C:\` and run it from there.

More info here: http://wills-tech-notes.blogspot.com/2015/12/cannot-install-java-semicolon-found-in.html

Answer (score 2):

The Error which you are getting is normally it throws during java update installation, Not, the first time installation.

Please kindly follow the below steps to resolve your issues. Let's give a try.

Step 1:

- Just want to ensure if you have already java installed on your machine partially.
- Follow the below entries in command prompt:

  - java -version - If it throws error we are good.
  - echo %JAVA_HOME% and echo %JRE_HOME%
  - echo %PATH% - If you see the Java entries you may need to clear all this.
  - echo %CLASSPATH% - Here as well as said in above.

If no results from the Step 1, Please follow Step 2.

Step 2:

- Check your C: drive for to verify there should not any Java installation folders. If yes, Please delete those.
- Clear all your logs from your machine(If it contains any existing java related logs)
      https://www.java.com/en/download/help/plugin_cache.xml

Step 3:

- Actually, we do not require to install the Java, instead we can download the Zipped java file and locate into dedicated drive.
    And then, make all your environment variables entries into this location. In, this case you are good i believe.

If you still face issues, do let me know?

Answer (score 1):

> [Try this and maybe you'll get your job done](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3671329?start=0)
>
> 1 Close the installer when you see Java error 1603.  (It has installed a
> bunch of files, but exits prematurely.)
>
> 2 Open javacpl.exe from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_XX\bin (or
> for x64, C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_XX\bin) where XX is the update
> number.
>
> 3 Uncheck "Enable Java content in the browser" on security tab and click
> OK to close Java control panel
>
> 4 Retry installing Java.  It usually succeeds for this time.
>
> 5  Open javacpl.exe again (see step #2)
>
> 6 Check Enable Java content in browser on security tab and click OK to
> close Java control panel
>
> 7  If it still fails, try uninstalling windows update KB2918614, then
> reboot and try these steps again.

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

- Run installer from c:/
- Run `jdk*...*.exe /log msi.log` to see installation logs, please attach 
  them if it won't help you understand a cause of the problem

In the related [JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8153368) an issue with an environment was a cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall KB3139923 helped in my case

Comment: although the answer looks helpful, I'd specify that you're talking about a Windows update

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with version 8 and the solution was to run the installer as Administrator (right click, then "Run as Administrator").